# run Angular4 webpack app without the gui - jest-preset-angular

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, jestjs

I need to create an app(can be in nodejs) that allow me to run a second app(angular4) without the gui where I a can trigger workflows and get that information.

The workflow is more or less like this:
App 1: calculator(angular 4)
App 2: calculator test api(nodeJS??)

1. Step 1: from App 2 a want to trigger a sum of two numbers in the App 1
2. Step 2: get the result of the sum and use it

The app use jest-preset-angular to run the unit tests.

Anyone has any ideas how to do it?

I was thinking somehow run the logic of the App1 via jest and try to get the results but I don't know if that is possible or if there is a better way to do this.

Is possible to run parts of the app 1 from another app like jest do?

Any help is welcome